# How can i check if date is on range on Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to check if today's date (in `dd-mm-yyyy` format) is in a given range.

My code only checks the day, not the month or year... Could you help me to see what's wrong?

#### Here it works fine...

```
import datetime
TODAY_CHECK = datetime.datetime.now()
TODAY_RESULT = ('%s-%s-%s' % (TODAY_CHECK.day, TODAY_CHECK.month, TODAY_CHECK.year))
if '26-11-2017' <= TODAY_RESULT <= '30-11-2017':
    print "PASS!"
else:
    print "YOU SHALL NOT PASS, FRODO."
```

#### But here it doesn't...

```
import datetime
TODAY_CHECK = datetime.datetime.now()
TODAY_RESULT = ('%s-%s-%s' % (TODAY_CHECK.day, TODAY_CHECK.month, TODAY_CHECK.year))
if '26-11-2017' <= TODAY_RESULT <= '01-12-2017':
    print "PASS!"
else:
    print "YOU SHALL NOT PASS, FRODO."
```

Comment: You should use YYYY-MM-DD format unless you want `27-11` to be before `28-10`

Comment: Also, why are you not just comparing datetime objects?

Comment: Like @cricket_007 said, this isn't the right way to do this. Much safer (and more accurate in general) to compare datetime objects.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are comparing strings. You should compare datetime/date objects

```
import datetime
TODAY_CHECK = datetime.datetime.now()
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("26-11-2017", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("30-11-2017", "%d-%m-%Y")
if start <= TODAY_CHECK <= end:
    print "PASS!"
else:
    print "YOU SHALL NOT PASS, FRODO."
```

or you can do

```
start = datetime.datetime(day=26,month=11,year=2017)
end = datetime.datetime(day=30,month=11,year=2017)
```

Comment: Alright, now i see my error i'll keep that in mind in the future...Thank you so much, i really appreciate it!